# Binding Enums to DataGrid ComboBox View

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am working with a WPF application, and I am working on a DataGrid that incorporates the use of dynamic content that must react to events,etc.

I have the following  ViewModel for the View that contains the DataGrid

```
public class HiddenFieldPanelViewModel
{
    public List<HiddenFieldComponent> HiddenFieldList { get; set; }
    public HiddenFieldComponent Component { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public enum FieldTypes{Constant,Variable}
    public HiddenFieldPanelViewModel()
    {
        HiddenFieldList = new List<HiddenFieldComponent>();
        IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

The only property on this model that applies to this example is the following enum property

```
public enum FieldTypes {Constant,Variable}
```

What I need to do when the DataGrid is populated is to bind the enum types to the dropdown that is in the DataGrid cell, here is an example of one of the DataGrid collection items after it would have been added
[image]

So for example, in the picture above, I would like it to have both of the Enum Values
from the FieldTypes enum.

In my XAML, I have specified the following:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Field Type" CanUserResize="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Height="20" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FieldTypes}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Value}"></Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The other columns are binding the data correctly, but this one is not.

I am not sure if there is a better way to do it or not. I have also written a EnumConverter from the IValueConverter to handle the string-enum-string conversions if that is ever needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pull the enum out of your ViewModel

```
public enum FieldTypes
{
  Constant,
  Variable,
}

// Don't forget to set up your INotifyPropertyChanged on your properties
// if they are being used for binding
public class HiddenFieldPanelViewModel
{
    public List<HiddenFieldComponent> HiddenFieldList { get; set; }
    public HiddenFieldComponent Component { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    // removed:
    // public enum FieldTypes{Constant,Variable}

    // will likely want to set up a property such as:
    // public enum FieldTypes {get; set;}

    public HiddenFieldPanelViewModel()
    {
        HiddenFieldList = new List<HiddenFieldComponent>();
        IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

These would be the namespaces you import into your xaml:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NamespaceToYourEnum" 
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

And then you can set up an `ObjectDataProvider` to bind the Combobox. Some sample XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>    
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EnumDataProvider" 
                        MethodName="GetValues" 
                        ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:FieldTypes"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- FieldTypesEnumProperty would be in your ViewModel -->
<ComboBox Height="25"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FieldTypesEnumProperty}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumDataProvider}}" />
```

Comment: Quick question, is there a way to set the selected item on the combobox according to that DataGrid Item?

Comment: See edit for an updated `ItemsSource` and a `SelectedItem`. Essentially you'd just bind the SelectedItem to whatever was being used to bind the row in your DataGrid. The property would need to be OfType FieldTypes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at something like :

```
<DataTemplate>
  <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=EstimateStatusValueId}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.EstimateStatusValueList, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Description"
            SelectedValuePath="EstimateStatusValueId" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: i tried this, and I still could not get it to display the enum values, thanks